# CSS firstline pseudo-element with multiple classes

Tags: css

I have an element that is controlled with the following css:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3 {
    ...stuff...
}
```

I want to apply the `::first-line pseudo-element`, but can't seem to get it to work. I know that:

```
p::first-line {
}
```

works, but not 
`.woocommerce::first-line  ul.products::first-line  li.product::first-line  h3 {}` or

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3::first-line {}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: `::first-line`, not `::firstline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `::first-line` not `::firstline`.

Using your selectors and nesting i got no errors.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/w5emen0z/2/).

Comment: Thanks, looks like it comes down to a typo and not spotting the difference in search.

Comment: No problem, next time try it again with an easy selector and see when you error occurs, if `simple selector::firstline` doesn't work, `complex selector::first-line` naturally won't either, break down your code and see when exactly your error occurs and search there.

Comment: even with the corrected spelling, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That has to be an error outside your current scope! As you see it works perfect in my fiddle.

Comment: Provide me with your whole enviorment and explain what is not working (even if it is the same issue, because it will have another error source, this particular code snippet is working). Oh, and if you have another question, you should ask anothe question! There is only one specific question allowed in one question, but feel free to post me the question link.